# Is sentence "I paint for 3 hours" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-tense

Is the sentence below grammatically correct?

> "I paint for 3 hours"

Google Translate translates from my native language to this sentence.  Also, I checked this sentence on [grammarly online checker](http://grammarly%20online%20checker), and it's result the sentence is grammatically correct.
Why? Because I reckon that this sentence must be like

> "I have been painting for 3 hours" (Present Perfect Continuous Tense)

but first sentence is Present Simple, but how it's may be correct?
Can Present Simple tense be continuous? I think "paint for 3 hours" is continuous action.

The sentence should mean that I started painting 3 hours ago and still painting yet.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Every morning I get up and have my breakfast. **I paint for 3 hours**, then I have my lunch.* Nothing wrong with that. There's also nothing wrong with ***I have been painting for 3 hours**, and now it's time for lunch*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think your sentence is action that repeats every morning. Or I'm wrong? I would to say that I'm painting just now at the moment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, oh, really, okay, solved

Comment: User98 - You are correct. There are almost no circumstances where a native speaker would say ***I paint*** (whether or not followed by an adverbial clause such as ***...for 3 hours***) to convey the information "what I am doing right now is painting". In fact although it's really easy to teach, the Simple Present Tense isn't actually used very much at all in English to refer to things which are happening at time of speaking.

Comment: The link is broken. Nearly any short sentence, in isolation, will be grammatical if the formula SVO is respected.

Comment: If the grammar of your native language doesn't distinguish between the sentences *I paint for three hours* and *I have been painting for three hours*, then the translation program had to make a choice without having a basis for choosing one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

"I paint" describes an action that has no definite beginning and end.

"For 3 hours," implies that the action has a beginning and an end.

Unless you're describing something that's part of a routine, this doesn't make sense.

"I paint for three hours each day," is an example of how the imperfect tense is used to describe recurring events that do not have a definite beginning and end.